# Updating a status of a record based on datetime in supabase

Tags: database, postgresql, next.js, cron, supabase

I am trying to set up a cron job on supabase, which looks at a table called 'matches' and gets all the rows with a status of 'waiting_for_players' where we've gone past the current time. For those rows, change the status to 'never_accepted'.

Basically, I want to change the status of matches from 'waiting_for_players' to 'never_accepted' for all the rows where we've gone beyond the dateOfMa

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT cron.schedule(
    'update-match-status', -- name of the cron job
    '*/1 * * * *', -- run every 1 minute
    $$
    UPDATE matches
    SET status = 'never_accepted'
    WHERE status = 'waiting_for_players'
    AND datetimeOfMatch < now();
    $$
);
```

I've ran this on supabase and here's what it looks like:

[image]

However, this cron job does nothing. The matches don't change their status.

What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this query run if you run it outside cron?  Seems weird that `datetimeOfMatch` has uppercase characters and it is not in double quotes.

Also: did you check in the `cron.job_run_details` table? 
PS: Every minute looks pretty aggressive, but you could have it as '* * * * *' for every minute.